# FastqGeneralIterator Output

Tags: biopython, fastq

I'm using FastqGeneralIterator, but I find that it removes the @ from the 1st line of a fastq file and also the information for the 3rd line (it removes the entire 3rd line).
I added the @ in the 1st line in the following way:

```
for line in open("prova_FiltraN_CE_filt.fastq"):
fout.write(line.replace('SEQ', '@SEQ'))
```

I want to add also the 3rd line, that starts with + and there is nothing after that. For example:

```
    @SEQILMN0
    TCATCGTA....
    +
    #<BBBFFF.....
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: can you show complete code, input file example and expected output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use, [String Formatting Operations %](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

```
from Bio.SeqIO.QualityIO import FastqGeneralIterator
with open("prova_FiltraN_CE_filt.fastq", "rU") as handle:
    for (title, sequence, quality) in FastqGeneralIterator(handle):
        print("@%s\n%s\n+\n%s" % (title, sequence, quality))
```

you get `fastq` print format, using `FastqGeneralIterator`

```
@SEQILMN0
TCATCGTA....
+
#<BBBFFF....
```